# What exactly is the difference between HIALS and HIALS-II lighting systems?

Tags: runways, aeronautical-charts, approach, airport-lighting

What exactly is the difference between HIALS and HIALS-II lighting systems? The symbols at the beginning of the runways are very different and I cannot classify them in a particular way. But in general, for most of them, either the HIALS or the HIALS-II header is used. What is the main difference between them?

[image]